# Redirect to another activity when finished service - Android?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service, I need to when `service` is finishing redirect to another `Activity` (but I don't need redirect from `Service`,I need redirect from Activity).

Comment: Use BroadcastReceiver to notify activity from service.

Comment: used `BroadcastReceiver` to send `finish event` to `Activity` and navigate to another activity from your activity

Comment: @ M D . Get me a sample ,please.Thanks

Comment: Yes,I need to see sample of BroadcastReceiver for my problem.

Comment: There no ready made code available for this. Search on _Google_ for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy paste this in your destination class

```
 private BroadcastReceiver refresh = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //write your activity starting code here
    }
};
```

in onResume method.

```
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(refresh,
            new IntentFilter("refresh"));
```

register your reciever.

in onPause and onStop method

```
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(refresh);
```

In service class.

call this when your service finishes.

```
 Intent ins=new Intent("refresh");
            sendBroadcast(ins);
```

Comment: @ Ribin Haridas .I should extend my class from BroadcastReceiver?In Service I separated process service for best speed . Can I separate BroadcastReceiver same service ? Thanks

Comment: I use form android:process=":remote" ?